# swift: recursive animation

Tags: swift, recursion, uiviewanimation

In my app I want to animate an array of Strings to give some instruction to users. My expectation is the first string fades in, maintains for seconds and fades out then the first string is removed from the array and the next shows and so on until the array gets empty. There is something wrong with my implementation however it's hard to debug (it seems the program would not be executed line by line), here is my code:

```
var text = [Text.text1, Text.text2]
@IBOutlet weak var paragraph: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    paragraph.alpha = 0
    showText(text: text)
}

private func showText(text: [String]) {
    if text.first == nil {
        return
    } else {
        paragraph.text = text.first
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 1.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.paragraph.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { (_) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.paragraph.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { (_) in
                self.text.remove(at: 0)
                self.showText(text: text)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is the first string shows three times and then I get an index out of range error. When I try setting breakpoints and click step over, it will skip the animation and completion blocks, and I don't know how to debug a function with a block as its parameter. And also even though I have

```
paragraph.text = text.first
```

after the first round, `paragraph.text` has been the second string but still the first string shows.
Similarly, it seems my terminate condition doesn't work: after two iterations, I've noticed the count of the `self.text` array has become 0, but the function didn't return, it goes to else...

```
if text.count == 0 {
            return
        } else { ... }
```

I'm a newbie and don't know how to debug blocks...

Comment: Have you tried debugging this using breakpoints?

Comment: What's wrong exactly?

Comment: @ZonilyJame I've tried using breakpoints but I don't know how to deal with blocks as the parameters of a function...

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is subtle and it's all in the second completion block. You have:

```
self.text.remove(at: 0)
self.showText(text: text)
```

You update the `text` property but you then pass the local `text` parameter which hasn't been changed.

Change the 2nd line to pass `self.text` instead of just `text`.

But referencing `self.text` inside `showText` negates to need to even have the `text` parameter. Either write `showText` to only use the `text` property of the class or better, only reference the `text` parameter. The latter has the advantage of not modifying the property.

To implement the latter option, change the two lines in the second completion block from:

```
self.text.remove(at: 0)
self.showText(text: text)
```

to just:

```
self.showText(text: Array(text[1...]))
```